# Programatically grant access permission to user in C:\ to create textfiles

Tags: c#

I ran my program in C# that suppose to create and write a file in C:\, but an error occurred saying that access to the path C:\mytextfile.txt is denied. Is there any code that will give the user permission in C:\?

Comment: Might it not be a better idea to write to a location that does not require admin privileges?

Comment: If there was code to easily get around security features, wouldn't that render the security features useless?

Comment: agree with @dandan78. Use a location that is indented for application data, for instance [AppData](http://www.blogtechnika.com/what-is-application-data-folder-in-windows-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes by using the manifest http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66259/Requesting-Admin-Approval-at-Application-Start or run as [different account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873796/asp-net-run-program-with-administrator-account) which has sufficient rights

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the code as an administrator. You don't need C# code for this, you need to change how you're running the code.
However, I suspect that you're trying to do something wrong. I'd guess that you're trying to store some data locally, and are using the root of C: for simplicity, when you should actually be using the standard libraries to locate the users folder or to get a temporary file.

e.g. Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)

(for other folders, use Intellisense to look at the other SpecialFolder children.)